# Freezing next and previous events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the below javaScript to control next and previous events.

**JS:**

```
var nextprev=setting.nextprev
    if (typeof toc=="string" && toc!="markup" || typeof toc=="object"){
        for (var i=1; i<=setting.contentdivs.length; i++){
            phtml+='<a href="#'+i+'" class="toc">'+(typeof toc=="string"? toc.replace(/#increment/, i) : toc[i-1])+'</a> '
        }
        phtml=(nextprev[0]!=''? '<a href="#prev" class="prev">'+nextprev[0]+'</a> ' : '') + phtml + (nextprev[1]!=''? '<a href="#next" class="next">'+nextprev[1]+'</a>' : '')
        pdiv.innerHTML=phtml
    }
```

**The Script included in the HTML as below.**

```
featuredcontentslider.init({
    id: "slider1",  //id of main slider DIV
    contentsource: ["inline", ""],  //Valid values: ["inline", ""] or ["ajax", "path_to_file"]
    toc: "&nbsp;",  //Valid values: "#increment", "markup", ["label1", "label2", etc]
    nextprev: ["&nbsp;", "&nbsp;"],  //labels for "prev" and "next" links. Set to "" to hide.
    revealtype: "click", //Behavior of pagination links to reveal the slides: "click" or "mouseover"
    enablefade: [false],  //[true/false, fadedegree]
    autorotate: [false],  //[true/false, pausetime]
    onChange: function(previndex, curindex, contentdivs){  //event handler fired whenever script changes slide
        //previndex holds index of last slide viewed before current (0=1st slide, 1=2nd etc)
        //curindex holds index of currently shown slide (0=1st slide, 1=2nd etc)
    }
})
```

The next and previous works fine, but I need to make the next and previous freeze to their positions i.e previous at first and next at the last. I am not too sure how to do that.

By freeze, I mean the below.

Currently when you press previous or next, they move to 1,2,3,1.. and so on .. I want them to be locked at the end. For instance, if my page loads at 1, when I press next, it should be 1,2,3 that's it. It should stop at last. When I press previous from 3,2,1, then it should stop at 1 instead of going to 3,2,1,3.. and so on. Hope this helps

You can see the working demo from the below jsFiddle link.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4xvcuz6h/1/)**

Comment: What do you mean "freeze to their positions"?

Comment: Currently when you press previous or next, they move to 1,2,3,1.. and so on .. I want them to be locked at the end. For instance, if my page loads at 1, when I press next, it should be 1,2,3 that's it. It should stop at last. When I press previous from 3,2,1, then it should stop at 1 instead of going to 3,2,1,3.. and so on. Hope this helps. - @artm

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/4xvcuz6h/5/ If the page is 1 disable prev link, If page == maxpage, disable next link, else add href. Handle click event only if href is set.

Comment: Shouldn't be there somewhere in the top of 'turnpage' function, a condition if (nextPage < allPages || nextPage > 1) { doTheRest(); } ?

Comment: @artm - Yes. Previous works perfect as intended.

Comment: @artm - Not sure how to add the logic for next. I shall try and see to achieve it. Thx again.

Comment: I added my answer, new link works for next as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/4xvcuz6h/6/

```
if (turntopage == 1){
    document.getElementsByClassName("prev")[0].removeAttribute("href");
}
else{
    document.getElementsByClassName("prev")[0].href = "#prev";
}

if (turntopage == totalpages){
    document.getElementsByClassName("next")[0].removeAttribute("href");
}
else{
    document.getElementsByClassName("next")[0].href = "#next";
}
```

and

```
pdivlinks[i].onclick=function(){
   if (this.href){ //only handle when href is set
        featuredcontentslider.turnpage(setting, this.className)
        return false
   }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. +1 and accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a line in your code which says:

```
turntopage=(turntopage<1)? totalpages : (turntopage>totalpages)? 1 : turntopage
```

It checks the current number, if it's less than one, changes it to total number and if it's bigger than total, changes it to 1, so it kinda goes in a circle. You can change it to this:

```
turntopage=(turntopage<1)? 1 : (turntopage>totalpages)? totalpages : turntopage
```

**EDIT:**

```
document.querySelector('.prev').style.visibility=(turntopage == 1)? "hidden" : "visible";
document.querySelector('.next').style.visibility=(turntopage == totalpages)? "hidden" : "visible";
```

[**Updated jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/4xvcuz6h/7/)

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I was looking for. +1. But can there be a possibility to add a class for disable? Something like the below. jsfiddle.net/4xvcuz6h/5 ?? It is done for previous.

Comment: I wanted to write that that doesn't seem to be efficient as function executes with current page number, but the  'if (turntopage==setting.currentpage) return; '  is doing the trick, thou unintended probably. ; )

Comment: @NKL edited the answer. It changes nex/prev's visibility, but you can do whatever you want

Comment: @Samurai - Super .. Thanks again .. This is great. But can you make it disable/enable like converting it into a span on reaching that position?